# Set JDK path in linux

Tags: java, linux, path

Something really weird occurs. When I type in:

```
which java
```

the output is like:

```
/private/me/jdk1.8.0_20/bin/java
```

and when typing in:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

the output is:

```
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24
```

I want to use 'jdk1.6.0_24' and I change all the things in '/etc/profile' and '~/.bashrc' to point it to 'jdk1.6.0_24', such issue still existed. The java I use is still 1.8. Why?

Comment: try: sudo update-alternatives --config java

Comment: What distribution are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your path as follows:

```
export PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24/bin:$PATH
```

don't use `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24/bin` unless you uninstall first the "default" java (if you use this then the java binary in /usr/bin will be found first, which is not what you want).

There is a caveat on this: the binaries in /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24/bin will be found before than the ones in the rest of the path, which is harmless because you only have java-related binaries on `/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24/bin`

caveat #2: make sure you are not redefining PATH after this line or in another script

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure you need to update-alternatives:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

and select java 1.6.0

Comment: sorry, I am on Ubuntu. Try to remove "sudo", or "sudo /usr/sbin/update-alternatives --config java"

Answer (score 0):

Go to your home, and show hidden file, then you will find the file .bashrc. Edit and go to the end of the file, then add

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24/bin
```

$PATH means the current path, in order to append the new value
Then, you will use jdk1.6.

Each time you write java -version, you will find the most recent version (jdk1.8), but your program will use jdk1.6

Comment: Which kind of program you are running?